# Add list in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add another list while I click on anchor or button in Javascript, which should contain multiple textboxes, an option-list and a delete button on the second and onward lists. Look at:

http://jsfiddle.net/KMLkn/3/

Can we use clone(jquery) for this?

Comment: Will the content of your `ol` list be the same upon addition of new set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-dynamic-form

View demo here: http://sroucheray.org/blog/jquery-dynamic-form/

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441061/problem-when-cloning-jquery-ui-datepicker

Answer (score 0):

Yes , it is possible to clone using jquery.
Just an example , see the fiddle here [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/KMLkn/8/)

Comment: hmmmm tht's gud but it's doesn't have delete button from second field and doesn't add third or more field