# Using the Clone Function(jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [problem when cloning jQuery UI datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441061/problem-when-cloning-jquery-ui-datepicker)

I used the jQuery clone function to clone a table with a datepicker function, but each time I clone a new table and try to click on its datepicker input, it appears on the default table that was cloned:

```
$('.clone_table').on("click", function() { 
    var $fromTable = $(this).closest(".contain"); 
    var $cloneTable = $fromTable.clone(true); 
    $(".contain:last").after($cloneTable); 
    var selects = $fromTable.find("select"); 
    $(selects).each(function(i) { 
        var select = this; 
        $cloneTable.find("select").eq(i).val($(select).val()); 
    });
});
```

Comment: This is the Table function `this.insertStatsTable = function() {
  self.insertInstanceRow($(".contain:first"));
  var $newTable = $(".contain:first").clone(true);
  $("tbody tr td select:eq(0)", $newTable).attr("disabled", "true").append($("<option />").val("*").text("AGGREGATE VALUE"));
  self.generateTimeColumns(defaultcolumn, $newTable);
  ($("tbody tr", $(".contain:first"))).remove();
  $(".contain:last").after($newTable);
  $newTable.show();
  $(".datepicker", $newTable).datetimepicker({
   onClose: function(p1, p2) {
    processStaticTable($(p2.input));
 }
  });
  return $newTable;
 };`

Comment: @deetu it would generally be better to edit your original post instead of pasting code in the comments.  It does have a 600 character limit after all. :P

Answer (score 2):

The [`clone`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) function MUST be called with parameters of `true,  true` (`withDataAndEvents` and `deepWithDataAndEvents`) for this to work. `withDataAndEvents` might be enough though.

```
$("#element").clone(true, true); //You might not need the last true!
```

Comment: its fine now, what i did was ` $(".datepicker", $cloneTable).datetimepicker("destroy").removeAttr("id");
                 $(".datepicker", $cloneTable).datetimepicker({
      onClose: function(p1, p2) {
       processStaticTable($(p2.input));
      }
     });`