# jQuery datepicker - date on cloned element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [problem when cloning jQuery UI datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441061/problem-when-cloning-jquery-ui-datepicker)

I have a problem with the jQuery `datepicker`. I have a `div` that i clone. That `div` contains an `input` element with the jQuery `datepicker` attached to it.

When i simply clone this element then the `datepicker` isn't working on the cloned element. To fix this i had to remove the `hasDatepicker` class from the cloned input element and re-initialize the `datepicker` method.

Now the datepicker shows up on the cloned element, but whenever i pick a date, then the date gets placed in the "original" input field instead of the field that opened the `datepicker`...

Anyone any idea how i can fix this problem..?

Here's a demo is the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/4VQkg/

Simply clone the element and try to pick a date fron the cloned `input` field. You'll see that the data won't get placed in the desired `input` field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this,

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4VQkg/3/

**Code:**

```
function initGui()
{
    $('.date-iso8601').datepicker();
}

$(function() {
    initGui();

    $('.clone').click(function() {
        var clone = $('.datepicker').clone();

        var cloneObj = clone.find('.date-iso8601');
        cloneObj.removeClass('hasDatepicker').removeAttr('id');

        clone.appendTo('.elements');


        $(cloneObj).datepicker();
    });
});
```

Comment: Updated the code with much neater