# Clone div jQuery UI Datepicker issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a div containing a few fields that can be cloned into another div. One of those fields use the datepicker ui. However, when I go to clone the div the datepicker stops working for the cloned input. I have used and edited the following from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441061/problem-when-cloning-jquery-ui-datepicker/2527248#2527248) but no luck

HTML:

```
<div class="add-child">
    <input type="text" class="child_dob" name="child_dob" id="child_dob" />
</div>
<button type="button" id="add_child">Add another child</button>
```

jQuery:

```
/* CLONE CODE */
$(function() {
    $('#add_child').click( function(){  
     var clone = $('.add-child:first').clone();
     clone.appendTo('#child');
     $(":input").each(function (i) { $(this).attr('tabindex', i + 1); });
    });
});
```

I really cannot understand where I am going wrong with it. Any help would be greatly appreciated

EDIT:

HTML:

```
<table class="portrait-table add-child">
            <tr>
                <th colspan="6"><strong>Children details</strong></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th><td><input type="text" class="child_name" name="child_name" value="<?php echo set_value('child_name'); ?>" /></td><td><?php echo form_error('child_name') ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Relationship to you</td>
                <td><select class="child_relation" name="child_relation">
                        <option value="Son">Son</option>
                        <option value="Daughter">Daughter</option>
                        <option value="Other">Other</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td><?php echo form_error('child_relation') ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Age</th><td><input type="text" class="child_age" name="child_age" value="<?php echo set_value('child_age'); ?>" /></td><td><?php echo form_error('child_age') ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>DoB</th><td><input type="text" class="child_dob" name="child_dob" value="<?php echo set_value('child_dob'); ?>" /></td><td><?php echo form_error('child_dob') ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Gender</th>
                <td><select class="child_gender" name="child_gender">
                        <option value="Male">Male</option>
                        <option value="Female">Female</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td><?php echo form_error('child_gender') ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Ethnicity</th>
                <td><select class="child_ethnicity" name="child_ethnicity">
                        <option>Ethnicity</option>
                        <option value="White British">White British</option>
                        <option value="White Irish">White Irish</option>
                        <option value="Traveller">Traveller</option>
                        <option value="Gypsy/Roma">Gypsy/Roma</option>
                        <option value="Any other White Background">Any other White Background</option>
                        <option value="Black Caribbean">Black Caribbean</option>
                        <option value="Black African">Black African</option>
                        <option value="Any other Black Background">Any other Black Background</option>
                        <option value="Indian">Indian</option>
                        <option value="Bangladeshi">Bangladeshi</option>
                        <option value="Chinese">Chinese</option>
                        <option value="Mixed Background">Mixed Background</option>
                        <option value="Any other Asian Background">Any other Asian Background</option>
                        <option value="Any Other Ethnic Group">Any Other Ethnic Group</option>
                        <option value="Not given">Not given</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td><?php echo form_error('child_ethnicity') ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>School</th>
                <td>
                    <select class="child_school" name="child_school">
                        <option value="Southwick Community Primary School">Southwick Community Primary School</option>
                        <option value="Valley Road Community Primary School">Valley Road Community Primary School</option>
                        <option value="Diamond Hall Junior School">Diamond Hall Junior School</option>
                        <option value="Highfield Primary School">Highfield Primary School</option>
                        <option value="Usworth Colliery Primary School">Usworth Colliery Primary School</option>
                        <option value="Hetton Primary School">Hetton Primary School</option>
                        <option value="Hetton Lyons Primary School">Hetton Lyons Primary School</option>
                        <option value="Other">Other</option>
                        <option value="N/A">N/A</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td><?php echo form_error('child_school') ?></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div id="child"></div>

        <p><button type="button" id="add_child">Add another child</button></p>
```

jQuery (I need each field name to be appended with _additional):

```
$(function() {
$('#add_child').click( function(){  
    var clone = $('.add-child:first').clone(true).appendTo('#child');
     clone.find("input").val("");
     clone.find(".child_name").attr('name', 'child_name_additional[]');
     clone.find(".child_relation").attr('name', 'child_relation_additional[]');
     clone.find(".child_age").attr('name', 'child_age_additional[]');
     clone.find(".child_dob").attr('name', 'child_dob_additional[]');
     clone.find(".child_gender").attr('name', 'child_gender_additional[]');
     clone.find(".child_ethnicity").attr('name', 'child_ethnicity_additional[]');
     clone.find(".child_school").attr('name', 'child_school_additional[]');

     $(":input").each(function (i) { $(this).attr('tabindex', i + 1); });
});
```

});

Comment: have you tried putting all code in doc ready? I mean the second code below the doc ready, put in ready and see if helps.

Comment: Yes I have done that now, my mistake. I have now cloned the element and the datepicker is shwoing up, but it is always adding the date into the first input

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few things for you to look at:

- It looks as if your second block of code is outside of the `$(document).ready(function())`.
- `var myDiv` is your button, it has no children.
- When your input is cloned, you get duplicate `child_dob` id's.

As for getting the datepicker to work on the cloned input, this should do the trick:

```
$('#add_child').click(function() {  
    var clone = $('.add-child:first').clone(true).appendTo('#child');
    clone.find('.child_dob').datepicker();
});
```

#### [Here's a simplified example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZzB3b/2/)

---

#### EDIT

I understand what your problem is now that you've added the full code. In your question you don't mention that you have a `datepicker` already assigned to the original `.child_dob`. It's a little bit messy, but you need to remove the `datepicker` from the cloned element, and then add it again:

Replace the line:

```
clone.find(".child_dob").attr('name', 'child_dob_additional[]');
```

With:

```
clone.find(".child_dob").removeClass('hasDatepicker').removeAttr('id')
                        .datepicker().attr('name', 'child_dob_additional[]');
```

#### [Here's another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FMFS8/1/)

Comment: The datepicker is shoping up now, but when I select the date it changes the value of the original input that I cloned. Any ideas?

Comment: By the way, you can remove the entire second block of code. You don't need it.

Comment: It is still doing the same thing. Since the first and second input have the same class it isn't working for the cloned input. I have removed the second block of code already as your example is the closest i've got to a solution so far..

Comment: It doesn't matter that they have the same class. A new, unique datepicker is assigned to each `clone`. Did you remove the `id` from your `child_dob` input?

Comment: I have updated my answer, there are more than one field that is cloned by i still don't understand why it isn't working!

Answer (score 0):

try calling datepicker after you element is appended

```
clone.appendTo('#child').datepicker();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q3f7h/).

```
var clone = $('.add-child input:first').removeClass('hasDatepicker')
  .removeData('datepicker').clone();
        var newCloneId="child_dobx_"+(child_count+1);
        clone.attr("name",newCloneId).attr("id",newCloneId).appendTo('#add-child');
```

I tried removing the datepicker class & data on the clone and then appended it.
It is working. Check if this is what is required.

Comment: There are now more than one field that needs to be cloned. I have updated my question because it still doesn't seem to work :(