# jQuery - Cloning a datepicker field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I'm trying to clone a table row and get a datepicker box working on all rows.  At the moment, the first one works, but not later boxes.

Can anyone offer any tips?  Any help much appreciated!

Here's the code:

**HTML**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://brenda.upreach.org.uk/plugins/jquery.datepick.package-4.1.0/redmond.datepick.css"> 

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://brenda.upreach.org.uk/plugins/jquery.datepick.package-4.1.0/jquery.datepick.js">  </script>

    <div class="clone_Associate">
<input type="text" name="DATE_SET[]" class="datepick" value="04/12/2013">

    </div>

    <div class="placer_Associate"></div>

        <a href="#" class="clone_trigger_Associate">Clone a new datebox!</a>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
    $('.datepick').datepick({ 
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy', showTrigger: '#calImg'});
});



$(document).ready(function(){
          $(".clone_trigger_Associate").click(function () {
              var total = $('[name^="UPDATE_METHOD"]').length;
              var index = Math.round(total / 2);
              $('.clone_Associate').last().clone().insertBefore(".placer_Associate");
              $('input.cl:last').val('');
              $('.clone_Associate').last().find("input[type='checkbox']").prop("name","UPDATE_METHOD["+index+"][]")

              // Date pick element
              $('.datepick').datepick({ 
                    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy', showTrigger: '#calImg'}
              );
              event.preventDefault();  
            });
        });
```

A jsfiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/dalepotter/aSG6e/

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441061/problem-when-cloning-jquery-ui-datepicker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aSG6e/15/

```
$(function() {

 var options = {dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'}

 $('.datepick').datepicker(options);

 $(".clone_trigger_Associate").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $newInput = $('.datepick:last').clone(true).removeAttr('id');
    $(this).before($newInput);
    $newInput.datepicker('destroy').datepicker(options);
 });
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this @Aamir Afridi  This is definitely progress, although the date shows as '04/12/20132013' when selecting a new data via the datepicker...  Also, for cloned fields, the date is always shown in the first/top field.  Do you know if there would be a way to fix these problems?  Thanks again for your help :-)

Comment: OK, thanks for your help...  It's strange that it doesn't seem to work - do you think there are any other options?  Will await your thoughts!

Comment: Check the demo. Remove its id works. Datepicker will give it a unique id. Otherwise it will reuse same id.

Comment: This looks great - many thanks for this!  I am now integrating this into my longer code to check it works there too!  Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42511/discussion-between-aamir-afridi-and-user2761030)

Answer (score 0):

Change this code;

```
$('.clone_Associate').last().clone().insertBefore(".placer_Associate");
```

with this;

```
var newDate = '<div class="clone_Associate"><input type="text" name="DATE_SET[]" class="datepick" value="04/12/2013"></div>';
$('.clone_Associate:last').after(newDate);
```

Comment: Many thanks for this @BerAenT  The real code contains at least 50 lines in the `clone_Associate` class.  Do you know if there is any way to change this so that the whole of the .clone_Associate box is selected, rather than using a variable...?